# How to generate random numbers with R for randomized clinical trails?

Tags: r, random

How would I use R to generate random numbers for a so called *randomized clinical trail*? Let's asume there are 350 persons and I need to separate them two *control*- and *intervnetion*-groups of the same size.

I know *simple* random number generations in R like that

```
sample(1:2, 350, replace=TRUE)
```

But does this have enough entropie to fit the needs of a RCT?

Comment: Check out `random` package. `randomNumbers(n = 350, min = 1, max = 2, col = 1)`

Comment: @d.b What would be the difference to the standard way?

Comment: From `?random`: The random package provides several functions that access the true random number service at http://random.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out the `randomizr` package:

```
install.packages("randomizr")
library(randomizr)
Z <- complete_ra(350)
table(Z)
```

this gives:

```
> table(Z)
Z
  0   1 
175 175
```

This is definitely random enough for an RCT!